# An algorithm Time limit exceeded

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

The topic link:https://codeforces.com/contest/109/problem/D

For the question, I'm time limit exceeded on test41

**I guess that the data structure used is not appropriate, but I have thought about it for a long time and I don't know where to adopt a good data structure, please give me some advice.**

algorithm ideas:

*This approach is somewhat similar to selection sort. First, find a lucky number, then swap the position with the first number, then start from the second, find the smallest number, and then swap it with the lucky number, so that the smallest number starting from the second is placed at the first position, the lucky number is now in another position, and its position is recorded.
Then swap the lucky number with the second number, and then repeat the above process. Special attention should be paid to the fact that we need to record the position of the lucky number we selected after sorting because the process before and after the position is slightly different and needs to be compared(This is explained in the code comments).*

```cpp
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;

// Judge whether it is a lucky number. if it is a lucky number, return true, otherwise, return false.
bool judge(string x);


bool static cmp(vector<ll> a, vector<ll> b) { return a[0] < b[0]; }

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<ll> nums;
    ll smLuckyNum = INT64_MAX;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ll x;
        cin >> x;
        nums.push_back(x);
        if(judge(to_string(x)) && smLuckyNum > x) smLuckyNum = x;  // Find the smallest lucky number
    }

    vector<vector<ll> > b;  // b[i][0] stores nums[i], b[i][1] stores i index

    int pos, origIndex;
    bool sorted = true;
    
    // b[i][0] stores nums[i] and b[i][1] stores i index
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        vector<ll> tmp;
        tmp.push_back(nums[i]);
        tmp.push_back(i);
        b.push_back(tmp);
    }

    sort(b.begin(), b.end(), cmp);  // sort by b[i][0]

    // If the original array is ordered, sorted == true, otherwise, sorted == false
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if(b[i][1] != i) sorted = false;

    // If the original array is not ordered and there is no lucky number in it, no way to sort, return -1
    if(!sorted && smLuckyNum == INT64_MAX) { cout << -1 << endl; return 0; }
    // If the original array is ordered, no sorting required
    if(sorted) { cout << 0 << endl; return 0; }

    // Find the position of the smallest lucky number, origIndex is the index of the smLuckyNum before sorting, pos is the index of the smLuckyNum after sorting
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(smLuckyNum == b[i][0])
        {
            origIndex = b[i][1];
            pos = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    vector<string> ans;
    // Traverse the nums array from 0 to n - 2, if  i is equal to pos(the index of smLuckyNum after sorting)  , continue.
    // We can swap the element at position i and the element at position origIndex, and record the position of LuckyNum after the swap in origIndex,
    // then find the smallest element from i+1 to n-1 and record the index in MINID, notice if i > pos, and  nums[MINID] > nums[pos] (because there may be a large number placed at pos), the element at pos is smallest number
    // if MINID < n, swap(nums[i](it is a lucky number), nums[MINID])
    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        if(i == pos) continue;

        string res = "";
        if(i != origIndex)
        {
            res += (to_string(i + 1) + " " + to_string(origIndex + 1)); // According to the requirement of the question, the index starts from 1, the result needs to plus one.
            swap(nums[i], nums[origIndex]);
            origIndex = i;
            ans.push_back(res);
        }

        ll MINID = i + 1;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            if(nums[MINID] > nums[j]) MINID = j;

        if(i > pos && nums[MINID] > nums[pos]) MINID = pos;
        if(MINID < n)
        {
            res = "";
            res += (to_string(i + 1) + " " + to_string(MINID + 1));
            swap(nums[i], nums[MINID]);
            origIndex = MINID;
            ans.push_back(res);
        }
    }

    // Finally we need to compare nums[n - 1] with nums[pos] when pos != n - 1
    if(pos + 1 != n && nums[pos] > nums[n - 1])
        ans.push_back(to_string(pos + 1) + " " + to_string(n));

    cout << ans.size() << endl;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++)
        cout << ans[i] << endl;
    
    return 0;
}


bool judge(string x)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
        if(x[i] != '4' && x[i] != '7') return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested loop used to find `MINID` makes the runtime quadratic in n:

```
for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
    if(nums[MINID] > nums[j]) MINID = j;
```

This will take much too long when n = 100,000. You need to find a better way to compute `MINID`.

Hint: You prepare `b[]` at the start, and then never use it.

Comment: Yeah, I originally wanted to use priority_queue or set in this place, but doing so would change b[i][1] when you swap the lucky number with the element at position i, so you must traverse the tree to find the b[i][0] in this tree to change its b[i][1],  especially when dealing with the situation of i > pos, you can't do simple pop. The logic is too complicated and I can't write it out. can you guide me in a more clever way?

Comment: Here's a hint: `b[i][1]` already tells you which element needs to *wind up* at position i. Suppose we have so far moved the smallest element home to position 0 in the array, and the "pivot" lucky element is at position 100. To move the 2nd-smallest element home, we would like swap positions 1 and 100, then positions 1 and `b[1][1]` -- but we can't be sure that the second-smallest element is still at position `b[1][1]`, since our swaps may have disturbed it. But what if we had a second array `c[i]` that tells us the *current* location of the element that was originally at position i?

Comment: I probably know what you mean. What you mean is that I don't need to write a for loop to find the smallest number. I can use an array c to track the movement of elements and use the b array to directly get the number that should be placed currently.